# "Not Authorized" when using Tigase XMPP with selfsigned certificated and Pidgin

Tags: linux, debian, pidgin, xmpp

I've installed Tigase XMPP server; I also created a self-signed certificate for the server. After installation I set the `--ssl-container-class=tigase.extras.io.PEMSSLContextContainer` option in the `init.properties` file and I copied my pem and crt files that I generated to cert folder. I started the server, and it started successfully.

In installation time I gave my server an IP address instead of domain name. In the Pidgin I entered a user name I also created the user on the server side using the `TigAddUserPlainPw` stored procedure. Pidgin gets my certificate and I accept it, but it still gives me "Not Authorized" error.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem in Pidgin is because you did not specified a resource name when you created your connection to the Tigase server. Specify a resource name like /home and everything will be alright.